# How to retrieve recycler view item position in side a textwatcher?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am getting NullPoniterExecption while retrieving the position inside CustomWatcher.
My CustomTextWatcher class :

```
public static class CustomWatcher implements TextWatcher {

        private MyViewHolder hol;
        private EditText editText;

        public CustomWatcher(EditText editText) {
            this.editText = editText;
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            int position = (int)editText.getTag(R.id.id_ans_text);
            Log.d("SUB", position+" "+s);
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }

    }
```

holder implementation class where I have set the watcher:

```
 public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        public EditText answer;
        private int position;

        public MyViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            context = view.getContext();
            answer = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.id_ans_text);
            Log.d("ss",answer+"");
            CustomWatcher textWatcher = new CustomWatcher(answer);
            answer.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
}
}
```

Within onBindViewHolder :

```
 headerHolder.answer.setTag(R.id.id_ans_text, position);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have a separate instance of CustomWatcher for each item in the RecyclerView, you can just keep the position in an instance variable.

First, modify CustomWatcher so that it takes the position as a parameter of the constructor:

```
public static class CustomWatcher implements TextWatcher {

        private MyViewHolder hol;
        private EditText editText;
        private int position;

        public CustomWatcher(EditText editText, int pos) {
            this.editText = editText;
            this.position = pos;
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            //int position = (int)editText.getTag(R.id.id_ans_text);
            Log.d("SUB", position+" "+s);
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
}
```

Then, create the CustomWatcher instance and call `addTextChangedListener()` in the `onBindViewHolder()` override:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder headerHolder, int position) {

    CustomWatcher textWatcher = new CustomWatcher(headerHolder.answer, position);
    headerHolder.answer.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);

}
```